# angularjs and angular 4 http request

Tags: angularjs, angular, http, angular-httpclient

I am porting an app from angularjs to angular 4

I encounter a problem with http request.

Here is a call in angularjs :

```
$http.post(/get_paginate_items_with_search', params).succes(function (data) {})
```

[image]
data is displaying

now in angular 4

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

declare const angular: angular.IAngularStatic;
import {downgradeInjectable} from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@Injectable()
@NgModule()
export class ItemsService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    GetItemsList(params: any) : void {
        this.http.post('/get_paginate_items_with_search', params).subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            err => console.log(err)
        )

    }
}

angular.module('module').factory('ng4itemsService', downgradeInjectable(ItemsService));
```

is not returning anything. the payload is the same 
[image]

but the request is different, there is no method and anything. In the Network tab, it is display as "pending". Do I have to make a special header and stuff to make it works ?

From the DOC of angular, they don't do anything particular to make it works.

I am missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot for Angular 4 likes an `OPTIONS` request. Can you check it again in the `Network` tab of `Chrome`, maybe you can see 2 requests to the same api (1 `OPTIONS` and 1 `POST`) then check the `POST` one. The response should be within the `POST` request

Comment: Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: I added 

        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type':  '*/*',
              'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            })
          }; 

and it works